# Error while performing configuration changes org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParserException: Template directory

Tags: java, api, wso2

Hi I am trying to customize WSO2 api manager. I get the below error when I run the product. Please help

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
[2019-08-28 6:41:24,642]  SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.server.Main handleConfiguratio
n} - Error while performing configuration changes
org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParserException: Template directory (D:\projects\ws
o2\product-apim-master\modules\distribution\product\target\wso2am-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
\null\templates) does not exist or is not a directory
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.checkTemplateDirExistence(ConfigP
arser.java:271)
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.backupConfigurations(ConfigParser
.java:168)
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.deployAndStoreMetadata(ConfigPars
er.java:178)
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.handleConfiguration(Main.java:231)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting the server with the following system property will solve your issue.

-Dcarbon.new.config.dir.path="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\resources\conf